# get a file in javascript in play framework 1.2.4

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm having an issue with adding xml file into my javascript, I'm working with play framework 1.2.4

My javascript has the following fonction :

```
 downloadUrl("example.xml", function (data) {
            var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var latlng = new     google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                var windowContents = "<h3>" + name + "</h3>";
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng, map: map });
                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, windowContents);
            }
        });
```

But an exception says that MapBillAction.example.xml action not found (MapBillAction is my controller)

I have a folder in view called MapBillAction it contains example.xml file and the others page .html

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So does that function exist in your controller? And how is the routes mapping? We'd need more information here.

Comment: There's no function I'm just using an XML file within javascript but play takes it as it was a fuction.

Comment: If there is no function, you have to make a route entry for it so Play knows it can serve it as a static file. Either that or place it in your `public` folder and update the url in your javascript to reflect this. Take a look at the docs, what you're describing is exactly how play is supposed to function: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/routes#static

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me ! I'm new to play, I couldn't figure it by myself.